# Thunderbird will not set up Existing Email address. after the last update ubuntu 20.04.2

Tags: updates, thunderbird

after the last update ubuntu 20.04.2, Thunderbird will not set up Existing Email address.After "the following settings were found by probing the given server", ....... unable to log in at server, ... etc
the settings are certainly good because they work on macOS Mojave

Comment: What's the email server? Edit your question to include the "@domain.tld" information - not your full email address.

Comment: @KGIII the same Issue happens to me after following the instructions mentioned in this [link](https://services-numeriques-personnels.univ-grenoble-alpes.fr/menu-principal/applications/communiquer-et-collaborer/zimbra-messagerie-/zimbra-messagerie--217614.kjsp) for example, and Thunderbird stops with that stupid message!