# after the last update ubuntu 20.04.2 Thunderbird will not set up the Existing Email address

Tags: email, thunderbird

Thunderbird will not set up the
Existing Email address.
.After "the following settings were found by probing the given server", ....... unable to log in at server, ... etc the settings are certainly good because they work on macOS Mojave

Comment: TB works fine for me with Ubuntu 20.04.2 so you need to provide further detail perhaps after reading [ask].

Comment: You asked [this same question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1320064/thunderbird-will-not-set-up-existing-email-address-after-the-last-update-ubuntu) yesterday. You were asked to give more information and you did not do so. I'm voting to close as it needs more details.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Thunderbird will not set up Existing Email address. after the last update ubuntu 20.04.2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1320064/thunderbird-will-not-set-up-existing-email-address-after-the-last-update-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

It's looks like a server side problem:
Thunderbird 78 can't connect to Courier Mail Server anymore because Courier can't handle TLS1.2.

Releted topic:
https://superuser.com/questions/1600014/thunderbird-78-doesnt-want-to-connect-to-my-courier-server-imap-how-do-i-mak